# Vungle ads not available

Tags: java, android, vungle-ads

When trying to play Vungle ads, I'm always getting the message `Ad unavailable: No cached or streaming ad available` from the method `onAdUnavailable()`

What's puzzling me is that it *used* to work and now it doesn't. It still works on devices where the old version of my app is installed, but when I build it now, it just says ads are unavailable.

I'm implementing Vungle as per their very basic instructions:

```
final VunglePub vunglePub = VunglePub.getInstance();

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    vunglePub.init(this, APP_ID);
    vunglePub.setEventListener(vungleListener);
}

private final EventListener vungleListener = new EventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onVideoView(boolean isCompletedView, int watchedMillis, int videoDurationMillis) {
        // Called each time a video completes. isCompletedView is true if the video was not skipped.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdStart() {
        // Called before playing an ad
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdEnd() {
        // Called when the user leaves the ad and control is returned to your application
    }

    @Override
    public void onCachedAdAvailable() {
        // I don't get this any more
        Log.i("vungle","cachedAdAvail");
    }  

    @Override
    public void onAdUnavailable(String arg0) {
        //I get this when I try to play the ad
        Log.i("vungle","Ad unavailable: "+arg0);
    }

};  

public void playVungleAd() {
    vunglePub.playAd();
}
```

`APP_ID` is correct (when I use an incorrect id, I get a  specific error), and internet connection is available on the device (AdMob interstitial ads work properly as well as internet in general).

I don't know what to try any more, I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're on one of the new versions of our SDK (3.x). There are a few things you can check:

1. Make sure you include our service in your manifest, https://github.com/Vungle/vungle-resources/blob/master/Android-resources/android-dev-guide.md#3-update-androidmanifestxml
2. If you've recently upgraded to version 3.1.0 (or higher), there are some additional steps required, https://github.com/Vungle/vungle-resources/blob/master/Android-resources/android-dev-guide.md#additional-steps-for-sdk-version-310-or-higher
3. I know you say you have the correct AppID, but just to be sure, use the one in red in the upper left of your app's page on the dash (not the reporting API ID)
4. If you're still having issues, feel free to email us at tech-support@vungle.com!

Comment: Yes, I went through all that. And as I said, I already implemented Vungle ads successfully, but then I changed some things and ads stopped working - even when I reverted all the changes by pulling that activity from backup. I guess I'll contact tech support. It would be nice if Vungle could report why an ad is not available.

Comment: Quick update on that- looks like this was a bug in version 3.1.0. Should be fixed in 3.1.1, which is in QA now. Thanks!

Comment: I had this same problem with 3.0.7, that's why updated to 3.1.0. to see if it will work properly. This is something I messed up