# Vungle: No cached or streaming ad available

Tags: android, vungle-ads

I am trying to integrate Vungle ads in my Android Project. Everything in my code is similar to what was mentioned in Vungle SDK - [Developer Guide](https://github.com/Vungle/vungle-resources/blob/master/English/Android/3.2.x/android-dev-guide.md) and [Advanced Settings](https://github.com/Vungle/vungle-resources/blob/master/English/Android/3.2.x/android-advanced-settings.md).

But when I call `vunglePub.playAd();`, `onAdUnavailable(String reason)` gets called with result *"No cached or streaming ad available"*. This happens every time I want to play add, whether or not I am connected to the Internet. Internet works everywhere, in Browser, Play Store, every other ad, even Vungle Ads on other apps can played.

My Listener looks like this:

```
private final EventListener vungleListener = new EventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onVideoView(boolean isCompletedView, int watchedMillis, int videoDurationMillis) {
        Log.d(MY_LOGS, "onVideoView");
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdStart() {
        Log.d(MY_LOGS, "onAdStart");
        // Called before playing an ad
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdEnd(boolean wasCallToActionClicked) {
        Log.d(MY_LOGS, "wasCallToActionClicked");
        // Called when the user leaves the ad and control is returned to your application
    }

    @Override
    public void onCachedAdAvailable() {
        Log.d(MY_LOGS, "onCachedAdAvailable");
        // Called when an ad is downloaded and may be played
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdUnavailable(String reason) {
        Log.d(MY_LOGS, "onAdUnavailable, reason: " + reason);
        // Called when VunglePub.playAd() was called, but no ad was available to play
    }

};
```

**P.S.** On my question looks exactly same as this one, [Vungle ads not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24998128/vungle-ads-not-available):

- I have added every thing required in my Manifest file.
- I have checked and rechecked my AppID.
- Moreover, TimSim's problem was solved by upgrading to a later version of Vungle SDK, I am already on the latest version.

Comment: Sorry to hear you are encountering issues and no ads. Can you please submit a ticket to us at tech-support@vungle.com so we can review the account and application? If you can also link me to the .apk I can run it through debug. Vungle//Chris